# Cannot get CSS to work for a Nested Div ID

Tags: css

```
<div id="content-wrap">

    <ul id="tag-list">
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
    </ul>

</div>



#content-wrap ul li {
    list-style: disc outside;
}
```

keeps overriding....

```
#content-wrap #tag-list ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

No matter what I use to target my UL with the ID of `tag-list` I cannot get the `list-style: none;` to work because it get's over-ridden by the previous one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this selector:

```
#content-wrap ul#tag-list li {}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess I need to get to sleep if I'm missing things this simple, I'll select this answer in 12 minutes when it lets me

Comment: :)) it happened to me more than once

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because you're trying to select an element with #tag-list *before* the `<ul>`, which doesn't exist.

You can either remove the `#tag-list`, remove `ul`, or combine the two with `ul#tag-list`.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this also, all of the examples use named elements instead of css classes..

i finally figured the following out (glad to hear feedback from more experienced css people)

```
   <table class="tbl">
   <tr><td>1a</td><td>1b</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2a</td><td>2b</td></tr>
   </table>
```

then from the css file you can define formatting for tr,td within a "tbl" table as follows

```
.tbl{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FF00CC;
}

table.tbl tr td {
    color:#112ABB;
    background: #FFFFCC;
}
```